# find a formula for a set of matrices

Tags: matrices

The four matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &  0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
have a clear pattern. I can write the first matrix as
$$
M_{ij} = \left\lfloor  \frac{(i-j+4)\%5}{4}  \right\rfloor
$$
But how to represent these matrices with one formula? for instance as a 16$\times$4 matrix, or as a 4$\times$4$\times$4 tensor?

Comment: Are they powers $I, A,A^2,A^3$ over the finite field $\Bbb F_5$?

Comment: sounds great! could you explain more?

Comment: Have you computed the powers of these matrices modulo $5$? You can try, perhaps it works.

Comment: I tried around on my computer, there is some pattern with matrix powers, but I cannot find a clear formula yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for: Let $P$ be the permutation matrix corresponding to the $5$-cycle $(12345)$. Then the matrices are $P^0$, $P+P^4$, $P^0+P^2+P^3$ and $P+P^2+P^3+P^4$.

Comment: This is great! it gives me an insight into what I am doing

Comment: google Toeplitz matrix for more information